# how to use before_action with after_sign_in_path_for and after_inactive_sign_up_path_for methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, devise, before-filter

I want to use the  `after_sign_in_path_for` and `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` methods to redirect user to some specific page, I would put these two methods and `before_action :authenticate_user!` all in the application controller, however, when the before_action method run it will be called on all actions, which will redirect my app to the wrong routes. Should I use `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:after_sign_in_path_for, :after_inactive_sign_up_path_for]` to skip authentication on these two methods?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate!


  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
      if user && user.is_a?(Vendor)
          return edit_vendor_registration_path
          elsif user && user.is_a?(Customer)
          return dashboard_path
      end
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
      if user && user.is_a?(Vendor)
          return root_path
          elsif user && user.is_a?(Customer)
          return root_path
      end
  end


  def authenticate!
      if @current_user == current_customer
          :authenticate_customer!
          elsif @current_user == current_vendor
          :authenticate_vendor!
      end
  end
end
```

I ran into this error `Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected`, I believe the program somehow created an endless loop that keep redirecting to the dashboard_path.

Comment: This mean, the before_action method should not be affecting these two methods? but, Im getting redirect to wrong routes when using before action and the two methods in application controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up a few things.

`before_action :authenticate_user!` is used for each controller action where you want the user to be authenticated so he can continue his request.

e.g. `after_sign_in_path_for` is a method of a devise controller which can be overriden like this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29

Comment: I know this, but it seems that before_action affect the redirecting of after_sign_in_path_for method, so how should I fix this?

Comment: please post some code otherwise it is really hard to help

Comment: i posted the code along with the error message im getting

Comment: Do the ``after_sign_in_paths`` as stated in the tutorial. About the ``authenticate!`` method i'm not sure cause I don't know what ``current_customer`` and ``current_vendor`` are calling. Where are these methods defined?

Comment: also i dont see the sense that a user is being redirected to dashboard/edit his account after signing in AND signing out.

Comment: oh, sorry I havent made an update on this question, I updated the code, the user is to be redirect to dashboard/edit upon sucessful log in and homepage upon sucessful log out